# How to make icons from Layers Panel in QGIS to be larger?

Tags: qgis, layers, icon

I need to change the size of layers icons  placed in Layers Panel of QGIS. 
I have tried to find some solution inside Settings/Options but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following to change the size of the icons within the Layers Panel (or [QgsLayerTreeView](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeView.html)):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize

tree = iface.layerTreeView()
tree.setIconSize(QSize(50, 50))
```

---

Note that this works fine for the raster icon (I'm guessing because it uses a static image which can be resized easily); but there is a limit to how large you can increase vector icons, probably because the icon is drawn dynamically from the style property and added to the legend.